# Show slopes of tangent lines to curve $2x^2 - 2xy + y^2 = 4$ at two points where it crosses the x-axis & y-axis are same.

Tags: calculus

> Show that the slopes of tangent lines to curve
> $$
> 2x^2 - 2xy + y^2= 4
> $$
> at the two points where it crosses the $x$-axis are the same.

In other words, show that the tangent lines at $(\pm \sqrt 2 ,0)$  are parallel.  Do the same for tangent line at $(0, \pm 2)$, where  the ellipse crosses the $y$-axis.
[image]

Is my solution below correct ?

\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = 2x^2 - 2xy + y^2 - 4 = 0
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Differentiate (1) w.r.t $x$,
\begin{align}
\frac{d(2x^2 - 2xy + y^2 - 4)}{dx} &= \frac{{d(0)}}{{dx}}\\
4x - 2(y + x\frac{dy}{dx}) + 2y(\frac{dy}{dx}) - 0 &= 0\\
4x - 2y &= 2\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}(x - y)\\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{(2x - y)}{(x - y)}\tag{2}\\
f'(x,y) &= \frac{(2x - y)}{(x - y)}\\
f'( + \sqrt 2 ,0) &= \frac{(2\sqrt 2  - 0)}{(\sqrt 2  - 0)} = 2\\
f'( - \sqrt 2 ,0) &= \frac{[2( - \sqrt 2 ) - 0]}{( - \sqrt 2 )} = 2\\
f'(0, + 2) &= \frac{(0 - 2)}{(0 - 2)} = 1\\
f'(0, - 2) &= \frac{[0 - ( - 2)]}{[0 - ( - 2)]} = 1
\end{align}
Hence slope of points $(\pm \sqrt 2 ,0)$ & $(0, \pm 2)$ of  ellipse  curve crossing $x$-axis and $y$-axis respectively are same or the tangent lines are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is ok. The curve crosses the $x$-axis when $y=0$, yielding the points $(\pm \sqrt{2}, 0)$. Assuming that the relation $f(x,y)=0$ defines $y$ as a function of $x$ in a neighbourhood of those two points, we van differentiate the equation with respect to $x$, obtaining
$$
4x -2y -2 x y'(x)+2 y(x) y'(x) = 0\Leftrightarrow y'(x) = \dfrac{y(x)-2x}{y(x)-x}
$$

In particular, $y'(\pm \sqrt{2}) = \frac{0-2 \times (\pm \sqrt{2})}{0-(\pm \sqrt{2})} = 2$. As to the points where the curve crosses the $y$-axis, you get
$$y_1'(0) = \dfrac{2-2\times 0}{2-0}=1, \qquad y_2'(0) = \dfrac{-2-2\times 0}{-2-0} = 1.$$

So we conclude that the slope is indeed equal at the points in question.

Comment: Moved my answer in the body of question as per your suggestion. Thanks.